# LinkedIn OAuth 2.0 Redirects to Wrong URL

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0

> https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A4200%2Fauth%2Fcallback-linkedin&scope=r_emailaddress

The above URL shows that I have the following URL for redirect:

> http://localhost:4200/auth/callback-linkedin

In the app settings I have the same authorized redirect URL. And it also redirects to same page but I get the following error:

> errors: Array [ "Something went wrong, please try again." ] response:
>   Object { status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url:
>   "http://localhost:4200/token", … }
>
> error: "\n\n\n\nError\n\n\n
>
> ```
> Cannot
> POST /token
> ```
>
> \n\n\n"

Answer (score 0):

According to [this stackexchange post](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/168643/internal-ip-or-localhost-on-oauth2-redirect-uri) localhost has been explicitly disallowed by some vendors.  Can you try 127.0.0.1 or a locally-resolvable DNS name?

Comment: Bummer, something went wrong.

We're having difficulty connecting. This is what I connect trying iP

Comment: Sorry, it was worth a try :-)